# Setting maxRequestLength programmatically

Tags: .net, request

There's a configuration value called `maxRequestLength`. In a config file it looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048576" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How can I set the value of `maxRequestLength` programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't!

`maxRequestLength` is handled by the [HttpWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) prior the call to the actual `HttpHandler`, meaning that a generic handler or a page is executed after the request hit the server **and** has processed by the corresponding asp.net worker. you cannot have any control over the `maxRequestLength` in your page code or an HttpHandler!

If you want to read the request length in code you can do that either through a `HttpModule` or the `global.asax` file, this is how it is done inside the global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IServiceProvider provider = (IServiceProvider)HttpContext.Current;
    HttpWorkerRequest workerRequest = (HttpWorkerRequest)provider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));

    if (workerRequest.HasEntityBody())
    {
        long contentLength = long.Parse((workerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderContentLength)));
    }
}
```

You could set the `maxRequestLength` in your `web.config` to its max value and call the worker's [CloseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.closeconnection.aspx) method in your code if the request length reaches the desired value!

Comment: The following seems like an easier solution to reading the setting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887016/how-to-access-httpruntime-section-of-web-config-from-codebehind

Comment: @MikeSchall The OP states how to change maxRequestLength, which is not possible, the code snippet above is how to read the content-length of any request, not the max-length

Answer (score 3):

After a quick google, it appears you cannot do it programmatically. [See here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1643396.aspx#4257779).

Two possible solutions:

1. Use localized web.config to configure a particular directory.
2. Use the `<location>` element in web.config to configure a particular path.